# Struts 2 jquery plugin grid (jqGrid) with groupField and rownumbers

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

I have set an `sj:grid` to have `rownumbers` and grouped a column with `groupField` as:

```xml
<sjg:grid rownumbers="true" groupField="['subTypeDesc']" 
          groupSummary="[true]" groupColumnShow="[false]"
          groupMinusIcon="ui-icon-circle-minus"
          groupPlusIcon="ui-icon-circle-plus" ..... >
```

The rows are grouped but the row numbers are not displayed for rows any more. Any comments ?!

As the `sjg` is totally based on `jqGrid` may be some `jqGrid` trick can help but I could not find any thing ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `rownumbers: true` can't be used (it will be ignored) in case of combination with some other options like grouping (see [the limitations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#limitations)) and TreeGrid.

The reason of such restriction will be clear after understanding of the implementation details. The collapsed groups (and tree nodes/leafs) still exist in the grid, but there are hidden. In opposite to data grouping (`grouping: true`) TreeGrid don't prevent the usage of `rownumbers: true`, the usage looks not really helpful.

Look at the rownumbers column on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-fa4-rownumbers.htm), which displays the results like on the picture below:

[image]

The row numbers corresponds all *currently loaded* nodes and leafs, even collapsed. Such look of the grid is misunderstanding for the user. Because of that the option `rownumbers: true` will be explicitly changed to `rownumbers: false` during initializing phase of data grouping.